# Windows WorkFlow Version 4 and Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, workflow

Can i develop Windows WorkFlow Version 4 applications using Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, Window Workflow Version 4 is part of the .Net 4.0 release, that came with Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio 2008 only goes up to .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

WF4 is a totaly re-write of the WF 3.5 and the APIs are different.